# 'Session' Object is not callable Flask

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a web scraping API with Flask, this is the code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.before_request
def login():
    session = requests.Session()

    url = "someurl"

    params = {'uid': 'username',
          'pwd': 'password'}

    session.post(url, data=params)

    return session

@app.route('/scrape')
def lezione(session):

    req = session.get("urlscraped")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
    table = soup.find_all(
        'table', attrs={'class': 'griglia_tab', 'id': 'data_table'})[2]
    if not table:
        print("List is empty")
    print(re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n', table.text.strip()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=5000)
```

Essentially this code login into a site and scrapes some data. What i want to do is to run the `login()` function before scraping anything, but when i run the code i get the error: `TypeError: 'Session' object is not callable`
What's wrong in the code?

Comment: if `login()` returns anything, then `lezione()` will never run.

Comment: But when i tested the code apart without flask it worked

Comment: Even If it works without flask that doesn't mean the same setup will work with flask.

Comment: Didn't know that.. so how can i fix it?

Comment: So do you want the `session` variable in `lezione(session)` to be the `session` variable you set in `login()`?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend turning `login()` into a regular function and just calling it from `lezione()`:

```
def login():
    session = requests.Session()

    url = "someurl"

    params = {'uid': 'username',
          'pwd': 'password'}

    session.post(url, data=params)

    return session

@app.route('/scrape')
def lezione():

    req = login().get("urlscraped")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
    table = soup.find_all(
        'table', attrs={'class': 'griglia_tab', 'id': 'data_table'})[2]
    if not table:
        print("List is empty")
    print(re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n', table.text.strip()))
```

Comment: i think `return session` should be changed with `return login()` otherwise you get  the error `View function did not return a response`

Comment: If you do that it would create an infinite loop.

Comment: My bad, forgot to fix def lezione()